# Django 1.8 Model Form not showing in Template

Tags: python, django, forms, models

For some reason is my model form not showing in my template

ive used is exactly the same before but now it´s not working ?
is there anyone who can help me, i'm stuck for a couple weeks an really want te get forward

**my html code**

```
{% extends "navbar.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content%}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><B>Let op!</b> Deze website is nog maar een testversie en kan niet altijd aan de eisen voldoen
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
speciaal voor ivo, dus het werkt wel gewoon... of toch niet

{{form}}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms

from .models import Trainingen


class TrainingenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Trainingen
        fields = ['Klasse', 'Locatie', 'Datum']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

#create your models here 

class Trainingen(models.Model):
    Klasse = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Locatie = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Datum = models.CharField(max_length=120)




    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Klasse
```

**vieuws.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import TrainingenForm
from .models import trainingen 

#  your views here.

def trainingen(request):

    form = TrainingenForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form

        }

    if form.is_valid(): 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

    return render(request, "Trainingen.html" , context)
```

Comment: Show us the `urls.py` file and name your files with their real names, with relative paths (especially the template, f.e. "myapp/templates/foo.html").

Comment: Does "speciaal voor ivo, dus het werkt wel gewoon... of toch niet" render in your template? I'm guessing it does not?

Comment: model fields should start with lowercase ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help,"speciaal voor ivo" did render in my template so thats why i got stuck. But somehow it works now so i'm happy :)

Comment: You should be using class-based views in 2016.